# MvvmCross with Xamarin.Forms and Custom iOS Renderer - Prevent Nav Swipe iOS - MasterDetail

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, master-detail

In short, I'm looking to disable the swipe gesture on the navigation for iOS in MvvMCross default template. Have done a ton of research and trials but been unsuccessful. This is for a personal/opensource project I'm working on. Thanks!!!

Details:
Using the MvvmCross 7.1.6 (latest as of 1/21/2021). I have implemented a MvxContentPage. The page has 2 joysticks on it. The page also has the hamburger turned on which I want. When using the app on the phone the left-nav flyout appears when moving the joystick. I have researched everything I could find, and am successful with Xamarin.Forms disabling the gesture, but in MvvmCross I cannot find a way to prevent the slide. I know there have been similar posts on other forums, but have not found anything that works. I was able to build a custom renderer using a Xamarin post from 2016 but it doesn't seem to hold (code below). I can confirm the renderer is invoked.

```
using AstromechControl.iOS.CustomRenderers;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AstromechControl.UI.Pages.JoystickPage), typeof(NoSwipeiOSCustomPageRenderer))]
namespace AstromechControl.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class NoSwipeiOSCustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
            UINavigationController navctrl = ViewController.NavigationController;
            navctrl.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = false;
            
            ViewController.SetNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures();
        }

       
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please have a try with  `UINavigationController navctrl2 = this.NavigationController;`?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT thanks for the note but no, that didn't work though... appreciate any other ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if anyone's still trying to figure this out in 2021... here's the fix...
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2306

Using my combination of Custom Page Renderer posted above, and this github link. I ended up with the following:

```
using AstromechControl.iOS.CustomRenderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AstromechControl.UI.Pages.JoystickPage), typeof(NoSwipeiOSCustomPageRenderer))]
namespace AstromechControl.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class NoSwipeiOSCustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage is MasterDetailPage masterDetailPage)
            {
                masterDetailPage.IsGestureEnabled = false;
            }
            else if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage navigationPage && navigationPage.CurrentPage is MasterDetailPage nestedMasterDetail)
            {
                nestedMasterDetail.IsGestureEnabled = false;
            }
        }

       
    }
}
```